# I want to save data from POST request to table

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm retrieving data from POST request and saving to UserSubjects table. It was okay while i was just saving and in entity it was **"private Integer subjectId"**.

**UserSubjects**

```
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| subjectId | int(11) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| userId    | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**UserSubjectsEntity.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "userSubjects")
public class UserSubjects {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="subjectId", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Subjects subjects;

    @Column(name = "userId")
    private Integer userId;

    public UserSubjects(Integer id, Subjects subjects, Integer userId) {
        this.id = id;
        this.subjects = subjects;
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public UserSubjects() {
    }

    // getters and setters..
```

But after i want to retrieve the data that i have in that table, i faced with the problem. I want to get not only *subjectId*, but all data that corresponds to *subjectId* in *subjects* table.

**UserSubjectsRepository.java**

```
public interface UserSubjectsRepository extends JpaRepository<UserSubjects, Integer> {
    List<UserSubjects> findAllSubjectsByUserId(Integer userId);
}
```

**UserSubjectsService.java**

```
@Service
public class UserSubjectsService {
    @Autowired
    UserSubjectsRepository userSubjectsRepository;

    // Save subjects in UserSubjects repository
    public UserSubjects saveUserSubjects(Integer subjectId, Integer userId, UserSubjects userSubjects) {
        userSubjects.setSubjectId(subjectId);
        userSubjects.setUserId(userId);
        return userSubjectsRepository.save(userSubjects);
    }

    // Get all subjects that have current user
    public List<UserSubjects> getAllSubjects(Integer userId) {
        return userSubjectsRepository.findAllSubjectsByUserId(userId);
    }
}
```

**CourseRegistrationController.java**

```
@RestController
public class CourseRegistrationController {
    @Autowired
    UserSubjectsService userSubjectsService;

    // Post request for adding subjects to userSubject table
    @RequestMapping(value = "courses/registration", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public UserSubjects addUserSubjects(@AuthenticationPrincipal MyUserDetails myUserDetails,
                                        @RequestBody UserSubjects userSubjects) {
        return userSubjectsService.saveUserSubjects(userSubjects.getSubjectId(), myUserDetails.getId(), userSubjects);
    }

    // Get all subjects of user
    @RequestMapping(value = "courses/show", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<UserSubjects> getAllSubjectsOfUser(@AuthenticationPrincipal MyUserDetails myUserDetails) {
        return userSubjectsService.getAllSubjects(myUserDetails.getId());
    }
}
```

**SubjectsEntity.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "subjects")
public class Subjects {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "title", length = 255)
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "codeSub", length = 255)
    private String codeSub;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="facultyId", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Faculty faculty;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="departmentId", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Departments departments;

    @Column(name = "ects")
    private String ects;

    @Column(name = "lc")
    private String lc;

    public Subjects(Integer id, String title, String codeSub, Faculty faculty, Departments departments, String ects, String lc) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.codeSub = codeSub;
        this.faculty = faculty;
        this.departments = departments;
        this.ects = ects;
        this.lc = lc;
    }

    public Subjects() {
    }

    // gettters and setters..
```

**POST request from Postman**

```
{
    "subjectId":"2"
}
```

Is there another way to save in Jpa data from POST request?

Comment: Could you also add a `Subjects` entity class? As well as POST request you're sending to your app.

Comment: I've add Subjects entity and POST request

Comment: It's not clear for me how `userSubjects.setSubjectId(subjectId);` can be set? There is no property `Integer subjectId` in `UserSubjects`, but only `Subjects subjects`.

Comment: Yes, I've changed this field into ```Subjects subjects```, previously it was ```private Integer subjectId```. Then i have to write get method to retrieve data from ```UserSubjects``` table, if i will just retrieve with **FindAll method**, it will retrieve only *SujbectId and UserId* without any information additional data about this subject. So i understood that **SubjectId** must have foreign key and i have to use JoinColumn to do it. @MaksimIakunin

Comment: But problem it that, i cant save data from post request to table, because there is no ```private Integer subjectId``` in entity and with attempt to save from POST request it will return me error. So the question is, have i used the wrong way of saving data from POST request or i used wrong JoinColumn. May be there is another way to get data or save? @MaksimIakunin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting `Integer subjectId` from POST body directly you should find `Subject` by `subjectId` and set it to `UserSubjects`.

To achieve this you need:

1. Create a separate [POJO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_Java_object) for you POST-request body:

```java
public final class AddUserSubjectsRequest {
    private Integer subjectId;

    public Integer getSubjectId() {
        return subjectId;
    }

    public void setSubjectId(Integer subjectId) {
        this.subjectId = subjectId;
    }
}
```

2. Use newly created `AddUserSubjectsRequest` in your controller (read more about that [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-response-body#@requestbody)):

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "courses/registration", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public UserSubjects addUserSubjects(
    @AuthenticationPrincipal MyUserDetails myUserDetails,
    @RequestBody AddUserSubjectsRequest request
) {
    return userSubjectsService.saveUserSubjects(request.getSubjectId(), myUserDetails.getId());
}
```

3. Create `SubjectsRepository` if you don't have it yet:

```java
public interface SubjectsRepository extends JpaRepository<Subjects, Integer> { }
```

4. Inject it to `UserSubjectsService`:

```java
@Service
public class UserSubjectsService {
    @Autowired
    UserSubjectsRepository userSubjectsRepository;

    @Autowired
    SubjectsRepository subjectsRepository;

    // methods left intact
}
```

5. Modify `UserSubjectsService.saveUserSubjects` method:

```java
public UserSubjects saveUserSubjects(Integer subjectId, Integer userId) {
    final UserSubjects userSubjects = new UserSubjects();
    userSubjects.setSubject(subjectsRepository.getOne(subjectId));
    userSubjects.setUserId(userId);
    return userSubjectsRepository.save(userSubjects);
}
```

**Note:** from now you should handle the case when `Subject` can be not found. It may happen when `subjectId` from POST-request is missing from `subjects` table.

Comment: I guess you do not understand me, I have to use POST-request method to get ```subjectId```. What i am doing is PMS (Personal Management System) of university. By this moment, I'm at point when **Student** choosing subjects from available list, if **Student** choose one of these *subjects*, i must retrieve id of that subject and save it to ```UserSubject``` table with authenticated user id. PS: I have separate table *UserSubjects* to save list of subjects of each student i.e ```UserSubjects``` will contain all subjects of all students.

Comment: As I can see, I understand you correctly. Have you tried my solution? The gist is that you cannot just set raw `subjectId` from POST-request. You should find corresponding `Subject` entity and set this found entity to `UserSubjects`.

Comment: Yes, i've tried. But problem stays the same, i cant take ```subjectID``` from POST-request.

Comment: Oh, so that was your problem! :) Then I would suggest you not to use UserSubjects entity in your controller directly. Just create a separate POJO for that. I've updated my answer accordingly. Could you try my solution again?

Comment: It works, thanks ) But i have to add to my ```private Subjects subjects``` these annotation ```@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})``` cause it gives me error.